# How to edit shipping method option in Magento?

Tags: magento

How to edit the shipping method option in Magento

> Admin Panel->System->Configuration->Sales->Shipping
> Methods->USPS->Allowed Methods

to change "Standard Post" to "First Class Mail"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i came up with the answer
Goto->app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Address\Rate.php

```
public function importShippingRate(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Abstract $rate)
{
     if($rate->getMethodTitle() == 'Standard Post'){
          **/* Change here  */**
           $shipping_method='First Class Mail';
     }
     else
     {
          $shipping_method=$rate->getMethodTitle();
     }
    if ($rate instanceof Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Error) {
        $this
            ->setCode($rate->getCarrier().'_error')
            ->setCarrier($rate->getCarrier())
            ->setCarrierTitle($rate->getCarrierTitle())
            ->setErrorMessage($rate->getErrorMessage())
        ;
    } elseif ($rate instanceof Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method) {
        $this
            ->setCode($rate->getCarrier().'_'.$rate->getMethod())
            ->setCarrier($rate->getCarrier())
            ->setCarrierTitle($rate->getCarrierTitle())
            ->setMethod($rate->getMethod())
            //->setMethodTitle($rate->getMethodTitle())
          **/* Change here  */**
            ->setMethodTitle($shipping_method)
            ->setMethodDescription($rate->getMethodDescription())
            ->setPrice($rate->getPrice())
        ;
    }
    return $this;
}
```